# What's the best way to store sensitive data for iOS/Android apps?

Tags: android, ios, security

I have some data to be stored with my iOS/Android app.

The data exists as files.

Are these files visible to users?

They can just browse the file directory & copy my files to their local drives?

If I have sensitive data to be stored with my app, what would you advise? Store the data with encryption?

Comment: please check this :- http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html

Comment: Depends on kinds of data ?

Answer (score 1):

For iOS you should store sensitive data in keychain.
Apple docs provide a detailed description regarding keychain storage. You can check the below link.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html